# Uncaught ReferenceError: vm is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onkeydown

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework

When i try to use a function for the onKeyDown in html it shows me the error like uncaught ReferenceError vm is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onkeydown

Html:

```
<input stopccp decimalpoint
      ng-model="vm.product.rate"
      placeholder="0"
      type="number"
      ng-change="vm.fillStarted()"
      maxlength="5"
      onkeydown="vm.checkMaxLength()"
      ng-click= "vm.hideScrollContent()"/>
```

Controller:

```
function checkMaxLength () {
  $log.log('checkMaxLength got called');
  //if(this.value.length === 5) this.value = this.value.slice(0, -1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ngKeydown` directive.

```
<input stopccp decimalpoint
      ng-model="vm.product.rate"
      placeholder="0"
      type="number"
      ng-change="vm.fillStarted()"
      maxlength="5"
      ng-keydown="vm.checkMaxLength()"
      ng-click= "vm.hideScrollContent()"/>
```